# How to make a void* argument hold its local result in a function, which is called with a struct *?

Tags: c++, pointers

How to make a `void*` argument hold its local result in a function, which is called with a `struct *`.

```
struct1{};
struct2{};

void f(void * ptr, const char* myChar)
{
    struct struct1 *myStruct1 = new (struct struct1);

    // write results in ptr 
    ptr = (void*)&myStruct1; // the result held by ptr is "" empty. 
}

int main()
{
    f(struct1*, char* char1); 
    f(struct2*, char* char1); 
}
```

How can I make `ptr` hold the result even though `f` is called with a different argument?

Answer (score 0):

The function argument needs to be a `void** ptr` so you can set `*ptr` in your function to the value. When you pass the argument use `f ( &callingPtr );` .

hth

Mario

Comment: No, it has compile error for *ptr = myStruct1 or *ptr = &myStruct1.

Comment: ah, you did not say so, so I wasn't really looking for errors: ´ptr = (void*) myStruct1;´ or short: ´ptr = (void*) new ( struct struct1 );´

Comment: I keep the f as void f(void * ptr, const char* myChar) because void** give me compile error. ptr = (void*) myStruct1  has no error, but it cannot hold the local result in myStruct1.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't proper C++ and doesn't compile, but I've done my best to translate.  You're trying to allocate space for a structure and store it in ptr, to be used in the calling function, correct?

If so, this code does what I believe you're looking for.

```
typedef struct _tag_myStruct
{
    std::string myStr;
} myStruct;

void f(void **ptr, const char* myChar)
{
    myStruct *myStruct1 = new (myStruct);

    myStruct1->myStr = myChar;

    // write results in ptr 
    // Note we dereference **ptr here to store the memory location
    //   in the pointer variable in the calling function (main() in this case)
    *ptr = (void *)myStruct1;
}

int main()
{
    myStruct *struct1 = NULL;
    myStruct *struct2 = NULL;

    f((void **)&struct1, "test1");
    f((void **)&struct2, "test2");

    std::cout << struct1->myStr.c_str() << std::endl;
    std::cout << struct2->myStr.c_str() << std::endl;
}
```

```
test1
test2
Press any key to continue . . .
```

edited for a bit more clarification